# Displaying images again which I have hid using a view all button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am stuck on the following issue,

I have created two buttons, One to hide images from the design class and one to hide images from the developer class. I now need the view all button to bring all the images back. This is where I am stuck!

Please, could someone give me advise as to how I could accomplish this (without using jQuery)?

I am a beginner so feel free to add your constructive criticism:)

```js
var designBtn = document.querySelector('.design-btn');
var developBtn = document.querySelector('.develop-btn');
var veiwBtn = document.querySelector('.add-btn');

var allImages = document.querySelector('.content');
var devImages = document.querySelectorAll('.develop');
var desImages = document.querySelectorAll('.design');

function removeDevImages() {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < devImages.length; i++) {
    arr = devImages[i];
    arr.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function removeDesImages() {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < desImages.length; i++) {
    arr = desImages[i];
    arr.style.display = 'none';
  }
}


function controller() {
  //Remove Developer images
  designBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    removeDevImages();
  });
  //Remove Designer Images
  developBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    removeDesImages();
  });
  //Add Images again
  viewAllImages();
}

controller();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.controler a {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: .8;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.develop {
  display: 'inline-block';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <img class="design" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg">
    <img class="develop" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg">
    <img class="develop" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg">
    <img class="design" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="controler">
    <a class="design-btn" href="#">Design</a>
    <a class="develop-btn" href="#">Develop</a>
    <a class="add-btn" href="#">Veiw All</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

See codepen link:
[link to codepen](https://codepen.io/underlight/pen/zRdxKO)

Comment: He's a slightly more modern way to do it, if you're interested https://codepen.io/Link2Twenty/pen/rJzVKw https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var designBtn = document.querySelector('.design-btn');
var developBtn = document.querySelector('.develop-btn');
var veiwBtn = document.querySelector('.add-btn');

var allImages = document.querySelectorAll('.content img');
var devImages = document.querySelectorAll('.develop');
var desImages = document.querySelectorAll('.design');

function removeDevImages() {
    var arr = [];   
    for (var i = 0; i < devImages.length; i++) {
        arr = devImages[i]; 
        arr.style.display = 'none';     
    }   
}

function removeDesImages() {
    var arr = [];   
    for (var i = 0; i < desImages.length; i++) {
        arr = desImages[i]; 
        arr.style.display = 'none';     
    }   
}


function viewAllImages() {
  var arr = []; 

    for (var i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++) {
        arr = devImages[i]; 
        arr.style.display = 'block';        
    }   
}
function controller(){
    //Remove Developer images
    designBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        removeDevImages();
    });
    //Remove Designer Images
    developBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        removeDesImages();
    });
  veiwBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        viewAllImages();
    });
    //Add Images again

}

controller();
```

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/MQvYqg

Comment: Thanks so much! Appreciate it!